# How to share text in custom listview?

Tags: android, listview, share, custom-lists

In this program, I have a custom `ListView` including a `TextView` & a `ImageButton`!
i want share a text in `SQLite` database but i don’t know how???

I’d be really thankful if u could help me with some instructions!

```
public class danestaniha_list extends ListActivity {    

    private String txt="";

    private TextView titrtext;

        private static final String[] items1 = {"Test Text 1","Test Text 2","Test Text 3"};

        private static final String[] items2 = {"Test Text 1","Test Text 2","Test Text 3"};

        private static final String[] items3 = {"Test Text 1","Test Text 2","Test Text 3"};

        private static final String[] items4 = {"Test Text 1","Test Text 2","Test Text 3"};

        private static final String[] items5 = {"Test Text 1","Test Text 2","Test Text 3"};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list);

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

         titrtext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pm_titrtext);

         String value1 = extras.getString("titrtext");

         String value2 = extras.getString("part");

         titrtext.setText(value1);

         int value2i=Integer.parseInt(value2.toString());

        if(value2i==1){

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.items, R.id.txt_pm, items1));   

            }

        if(value2i==2){

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.items, R.id.txt_pm, items2));   

            }

        if(value2i==3){

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.items, R.id.txt_pm, items3));   

            }

        if(value2i==4){

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.items, R.id.txt_pm, items4));   

            }

        if(value2i==5){

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.items, R.id.txt_pm, items5));   

            }
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){

    ImageButton btn_share = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_share);

    btn_share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,titrtext.ge  tText().toString());

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "iran");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share with ..."));

        }

    });

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "share"?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There isn't any code related to the SQLite DB here. Please paste code relevant to the DB.

Comment: I believe the OP wishes to use a ListView to display database contents. If that's the case, you might check the following tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#cursor

Comment: If you want to share on SQLITE database hen you have to use it.

Comment: Would you share your activity layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this.

```
private void shareIt(String yourText) {
        try {

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, yourText);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```